# Snap two objects face to face in object mode?

Tags: snapping

For the love of god how do you snap two objects face to face? I've read on this forum and I've seen videos but I'm missing something fundamental about blender. I'm thinking it can't be this hard, so I'm probably barking up the wrong tree.

What I'm doing is making a model of a house so sticking the inner walls to the outer walls etc is something that I was thinking could be done in "object mode" by moving objects around.

Like, is snap point always based around the object origin? It's apparent when using snap to increment (grid). Do I have to set the object origin to align with a face on the two objects before aligning it to another object or what?

What I'm getting is moving an object into the other the "snap" circle appears and when I release the two objects are intersecting quite a lot.

/Lars-Erik

Comment: Do you want to snap 2 objects so their outer faces touch? Then this is doable with just Snap during transform enabled and set either to Vertex (like in [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHHk.gif)) or to Edge / Face depending on the case.

Comment: Maximal zoom and set "Snap to Increment". Then just move the object to the right position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this:

- Select the object you want to snap it to the other object
- switch to edit mode
- switch to face selection
- Select the face you want it to be the one touching the other object
- Hit Shift+S
- choose `Cursor to selected`
- Hit Ctrl + Alt + Shift + C and choose `Origin to 3D Cursor`
- switch to object mode
- Select the object you want to snap another object to it
- Enter to edit mode
- Switch to Face Selection
- Select the face you want to snap the other object to
- Hit Shift+S
- choose `Cursor to selected`
- switch to object mode
- Select the object you want to snap it to the other object
- Hit Shift+S and choose `selected to cursor`
- That's it
- you need to set the origin of the snapped object back to normal using Ctrl + Alt + Shift + C and choose `Origin to Geometry`

Comment: @LarsErik  you are welcome. Hahaa, good luck!

Comment: Or in other software:

Select start point, 
Select end point, 
Snap.

I really wish Blender would incorporate this..