# Snapping a randomly oriented face to another randomly orientated face?

Tags: snapping

for the life of me I cannot find an answer to this seemingly easy operation. In CAD there's this command called "align" where I can simply align points on a polygon to the other points of a polygon, thus perfectly aligning the 2 faces together. However I just simply cannot do that in blender. I have tried snapping with all kinds of options on, changing the normals or the object, resetting the origin point, using different addons (works but very unreliable). I must be missing something very fundamental. A simple example is this: how do I perfectly align the blue face of that triangle tot the blue face of that square? Both are rotated randomly. I want the result to be the triangle over the square, in the square's orientation.[image]

Comment: Do you want to move the entire object, or just the face?

Comment: the entire object.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20891/how-to-snap-the-center-of-a-face-to-another-face   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131518/fastest-way-to-snap-two-faces-together-by-aligning-their-centers-in-non-standard    https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73177/snap-two-objects-face-to-face-in-object-mode

Comment: There are 2 possible routes in the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156469/35559).. depending on how your object axes happen to be aligned to the faces. Some things become a little easier in 2.81, where you will be able to manipulate object axes directly.

Comment: im sorry im quite new at this, how does one manipulate object axes directly in 2.81? thats the version i have.

Comment: but i will check out the answers thank you

Comment: i was able to use the empty method to align the faces, but i cannot orientate the edge of the triangle to the edge of the box.

Comment: None of the solution provided can help this problem. it seems that it's very difficult for blender to rotate an object exactly to a random angle. this creates a problem to some of the most basic operations, say a roof slope is 1:12, there is not a precise degree to this angle, but if one were to make a simple 200mm flat roof, it is impossible to rotate the roof to that said slope.